How do I integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty }x^3f(x)dx$ by parts when I know $\left\langle x \right\rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty }xf(x)dx$?
I am trying to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty }x^3f(x)dx$ by parts in order to get it in terms of $\left\langle x \right\rangle$ where $\left\langle x \right\rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty }xf(x)dx$.
$f(x) = Ax^2\exp(-\alpha x^2)$ and so $f(0) = f(\infty) = 0$.
I have decided to set $u=x^2$ and $dv = xf(x)$ which results in $I = \left[ x^2\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx \right]_0^\infty - \int_{0}^{\infty}2x\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx  \right)dx$.
I think this equation then reduces to $0$ which is not what the correct answer is. I am expecting that it is proportional to $\left\langle x \right\rangle^3$.
The background for this integral is that I have calculated the flux of molecules $\frac{dN}{dt}$ through a hole which is proportional to their mean velocity $\left\langle v \right\rangle$. I now want to calculate $\frac{dE}{dt}$ by multiplying the integrand by $mv^2/2$. I have used $x$ in the body of the question for clarity.

"This equation then reduces to $0$". How?

I strongly suggest you double-check your calculations. When you define $dv=xf(x), dx$, you should find a function $v$ (antiderivative), s. t. it satisfies the previous equation. What you have done is integrated it over the whole domain, getting a number instead of a function.
Also, are there any properties of the distribution we should know about? Is it a known distribution, or may be we know something about it being odd / even?

Unless there's some clever trick to rearrange $I = - \int_{0}^{\infty}2x\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx  \right)dx$, I assumed it would integrate to $x^2\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx  \right)dx$ which would cancel with the other term.

@EgorLarionov $f(x)$ is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution but I assumed from the wording of the question that it doesn't want you to write out the whole distribution and that there was a trick to just rearrange it.

The inner integral should be $\int_0^x sf(s),ds$.

There is no trick, because the shape of the distribution significantly affects the moments (for examply, it's indefinite for Cauchy distribution).
In your case, you just need to use the integration by parts, properly choosing the function:
$$
\langle x^3 \rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) \, dx = 
A\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 \cdot x^2 \exp{(-\alpha x^2)} \, dx = 
A\int_{0}^{\infty} x^5 \exp{(-\alpha x^2)} \, dx
$$
To use integration by parts, let's define:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
u &= x^4 \\
dv &= -2\alpha \exp{(-\alpha x^2)} \, dx = d(\exp{(-\alpha x^2)}) 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then the integral becomes:
$$
\langle x^3 \rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) \, dx = 
-\frac{A}{2\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty} u \, dv = 
-\frac{A}{2\alpha}(\underbrace{uv}_{\text{= 0 because}\\\text{of the bounds}}|_0^\infty - \int_{0}^{\infty}v \, du) = 
\frac{4A}{2\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 \exp{(-\alpha x^2)} \, dx
$$
Rewriting this integral in a slightly different form, one obtains:
$$
\langle x^3 \rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 f(x) \, dx = 
\frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty} x \cdot Ax^2 \exp{(-\alpha x^2)} \, dx =
\frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) \, dx =
\frac{2}{\alpha}\langle x \rangle
$$

In $dv$ a factor $x$ is missing in the middle expression. There is a factor $4$ missing in $du=4x^3,dx$?

Yeah, sorry, thought I had it taken out in front of the integral. I'll fix it.
